# Configuring a Rails app for Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, nginx, passenger

I just set up Passenger and nginx to host a Rails 4.2 app. After moving the app to the server, precompiling the static assets, moving config stuff in ENV variables and making sure it was running in production mode, I was wondering if there is any other configuration I should be doing **within the Rails app** in order to increase performance?

For example, I know that for running an app with Unicorn, I had to add a `unicorn.rb` with some config settings within my `app/config/`. Is something like this needed for Passenger?

Thanks!